# Stackoverflow with recursive function

Tags: recursion, f#, stack-overflow

```
let rec f a p n = if p n then a else a + f a p ( n - 1 )
let a, p, n = 3, ( fun x -> x = 1 ), 4
f a p n
```

Getting stackoverflow when n <= 0. Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Trying to build rep here. Why the down vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `p` = `fun x -> x = 1` which, of course, checks if `x` is 1.

Your recursive call uses `p` on `n`, otherwise decrements `n`.

This will cause n to become more and more negative, resulting in infinite recursion since n will never be 1.  To solve this you need to not call `p` with a value of `n` less than 1 or change your check function to do something other than check for a value of 1.

Maybe try `let a, p, n = 3, ( fun x -> x <= 1 ), 4`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if `f` were made tail-recursive then the code would "work" (i.e. not crash) with `p` as-is, as `n` would eventually underflow and count down from `Int32.Max` to `1`.